# How do I store the incremented value and output it using 8086 DOS assembly language?

Tags: assembly, increment, x86-16, dosbox

The goal is that whenever the user inputs the letter "s" it should increment and store but it increments one time only and it doesn't display the newer increment. Sorry for being dumb. Thanks in advance.

[image: dosbox screenshot]

```
dosseg

    .model small
    
    .stack
    
    .data 
    
        msg1  db "[S] Choose size $"    
        msg2  db "[S] Small Item $" 
        msg3  db "Small item has been stored: $"    
        msg4 db "Do you want to continue type x or y:  $"
            
    .code
    
    base:
        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax
        
        mov ah, 6
        mov bh, 30H
        mov cx, 0
        mov dx, 184fH
        int 10h 
        
    choose:
        mov ah, 02
        mov bh, 0
        mov dh, 15
        mov dl, 30
        int 10h
        
        mov dx,offset msg1 ;Choose a size:
        mov ah,09
        int 21h
        
        mov dl, 's'
        mov ah, 1 ;Condition
        int 21h         
        cmp al, dl
        je s        
        
        mov ah, 4ch
        int 21h 
    s:          
        mov ah, 02
        mov bh, 0
        mov dh, 18 ; Position of the message db
        mov dl, 30
        int 10h
    
        mov dx, offset msg3; Small item has been stored;
        mov ah, 9 ;
        int 21h     
        
        mov dl, dh
        inc dl ; increment
        add dl, 48  
        mov al, dl  
        mov ah, 2h; code for printing
        int 21h     
        
        jmp continue    
    
    continue:   
            
        mov ah, 02
        mov bh, 0
        mov dh, 10 ;Position of the message db
        mov dl, 30
        int 10h
    
        mov dx, offset msg4
        mov ah, 9 ;
        int 21h
        
        mov dl, 'y'
        mov ah, 1 ; condition
        int 21h
        
        cmp al, dl
        je choose
        
        mov ah, 4ch
        int 21h     
        
    end base
```

Comment: In future, don't delete and repost your question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71957312/how-do-i-store-the-incremented-value-and-output-it-in-assembly-language), just edit to improve it.  This one is a bit more minimal in its [mcve], but still not clear to me what you want to increment and what *should* happen.  Also, what do you see when you single-step it in a debugger.  Learning to use a debugger will *very* quickly pay for itself in time saved learning assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as far as I understood you want to store the amount of small items chosen by the user. Well the code right now does nothing in terms of storing the thing as far as I can see. So first you need to reserve some space for the amount of small item. So something like this (I do not know which assembler you are using, I could tell you the exact syntax if you give me that):

```
.data
smallItems dw 0h
```

Then inside the `s:` label you need to increment this variable value.

```
inc [smallItems]
```

As I have mentioned before I have only used NASM as assembler so I do not know your assembler's syntax.

Edit: OK I found your assembler to be MASM, I have updated the code accordingly

Comment: The code in the question already does `mov ax,@data`  / `mov ds,ax` at the start of the code.  You don't need to do it again; it's using a "small" memory model so all static data is  reachable with the same DS.  So you just need `inc word ptr [smallItems]` (DS is already the default, you don't want it to emit an extra prefix, although IDK if MASM would do that.  Also, it's MASM, so `inc [smallItems]` would magically imply the operand-size)

Comment: MASM doesn't accept `0x00`, only `0` or `0h`, and I think you unfortunately have to omit the `:` after the label; MASM doesn't have normal labels on data, only "variables" like `smallItems dw 0` so there's a size magically associated with the symbol name.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the information. I fixed the errors. But wow you just made me hate MASM :) especially with not being able to use 0x00

Comment: Update: I double-checked where I'd heard that; Michael Petch says newer versions of MASM do allow `label: dw 0`: [How to store 4 characters in a define doubleword in assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/99179402).  And yeah, I strongly dislike MASM's syntax design.  [Confusing brackets in MASM32](//stackoverflow.com/q/25129743) is totally insane.  Overall, it's trying too hard to be a "high level" assembler for people who wish they weren't writing in asm, which was a use-case for asm back in the really early days when major things like DOS itself were done in pure asm.

Comment: NASM sticks closer to a simpler mental model of what an assembler is, just parsing text and emitting bytes into the output file at the current position (or into the current section for object files, not flat binaries), based on simple rules.